# Error in migrated Delphi project (2010 - 10.2)

Tags: delphi, compatibility, delphi-2010, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm migrating a project made with Delphi 2010 to Delphi 10.2.
After installing all the dependencies with their updated version, this error happens:

[image]

It doesn't give me the line and I cannot put a breakpoint anywhere in file Data.DBXCommon.

The error occurs before the Application.Initialize (and that's the first line of the program) in the project dpr file.

The erros message is: **Project Server.exe raised exception class EListError with message 'Duplicates not allowed'.**

Comment: Do you have breakpoints enabled? How about Use Debug DCUs? FWIW, I don't see any error message.

Comment: An exception which happens before `Application.Initialize` tells me that it occurs in the `initialization` section of some unit.

Comment: @JerryDodge forgot to put the error... it's in the initialize of the project dpr file. I'm searching for this "Debug DCU" if it can help me

Comment: That under Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Compiling > 'Use debug .dcus'

Comment: You should probably first make sure your project is switched to `Debug` configuration. You don't want to enable that for `Release`.

Comment: @JerryDodge Found the duplication, is loading a list of connections: [ASAConnection, ASEConnection, FBConnection, OracleConnection, etc..] and it's duplicating BlackfishSQLCONNECTION. Any ideia where that list comes from? It's not from the 'Data Explorer' tab in the IDE

Comment: Depends - what kind of "dependencies" do you have?

Comment: @JerryDodge , Well, turns out there's a file in the bin folder called dbxconnections.ini and there was 2 connections with the same name. Thank you \0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's an ini file called dbxconnections.ini in the bin folder and there was 2 entries of the same connection.

Comment: It seems like one of your dependencies must have registered this blindly without first checking if it was already there.

Comment: Impossible to know this from the question.

Comment: Yes, what you suggest me to do?